# How To Concat search in laravel scout (meilisearch)

Tags: php, laravel, meilisearch

in laravel code

```
Model::where(DB::raw('CONCAT(name, " " ,surname)'), 'like', '%'.$request->input('search').'%')
```

how to use in laravel scout meilisearch

Comment: I think this question is not properly presented, but if I understand it correctly, you are looking to do a search of the name and surname to exact match. I'm also interested in it. Could you please edit your question to make it more clear and increase the chances of an answer? Thanks!